# Is this a valid SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

QUESTION: Which team has the youngest athlete, and what is that athlete's name?

```
SELECT athleteFirstName, athleteLastName, teamName
FROM team t JOIN athlete a ON t.teamId = a.teamId
WHERE athleteDateOfBirth = (SELECT MAX(athleteDateOfBirth)
                            FROM team JOIN athlete ON team.teamId = athlete.teamId)
GROUP BY teamName, athleteFirstName, athleteLastName;
```

So I have connected two tables and am trying to solve for that question. I have tried DATEDIFF and all I get are errors. Many different errors.

Would that subquery work?

Like, does it make sense or will my teacher mark it as incorrect since I haven't used DATEDIFF? I was also a little confused if I need to add a GROUP BY statement in the subquery.

Comment: It is fine and welcome to ask Homework question if the question itself follow guideline, which I'll suggest including sample data, expect output, clear explaination of logic and some DDL. also don't forget to tag your DBMS.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @T.Peter sorry I'm kinda new to this site and with SQL itself, I tagged the DBMS just now

Comment: @RachelD Please check my answer and let me know does it serve your purpose or not. Best wishes. :-)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, and sorry I just added it, i'll keep it in mind for next time

Comment: 1) Always post your actual error. 2) Always provide sample data and expected results. Even if your teacher doesn't provide any, make some up. The creation of data + results will deepen your understanding of the question and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to find youngest:

In sql server:

```
SELECT athleteFirstName, athleteLastName, teamName 
FROM team t JOIN athlete a ON t.teamId = a.teamId
where athleteDateOfBirth= (select top 1 athleteDateOfBirth from athlete 
order by athleteDateOfBirth desc )
```

In mysql:

```
SELECT athleteFirstName, athleteLastName, teamName 
FROM team t JOIN athlete a ON t.teamId = a.teamId
where athleteDateOfBirth= (select athleteDateOfBirth from athlete 
order by athleteDateOfBirth desc limit 1)
```

Comment: @Kazi Mohammad Ali Nur, that would calculate the oldest :) I am looking for the youngest person throughout my athlete table. I was also wondering if you think this would be 'correct' code? I have only seen people use DATEDIFF when calculating youngest people

Comment: Extremely sorry that i miscuided you. I am changing my answer. You need youngest athlete from each team right?

Comment: I just need the youngest person out of all the athletes

Comment: I got it now. You need youngest person from athlete table along with it's team id. I have changed my answer. Which dbms you are using?

Comment: This worked thank you so much! I was using SQL server. Sorry to everyone I confused and wasted their time without me stating that..

Comment: I have add sql-server tag. If it helped you please accept this answer by clicking green check.

Comment: Thanks. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
SELECT athleteFirstName,
       athleteLastName,
       teamName
FROM team t
JOIN athlete a ON t.teamId = a.teamId
WHERE athleteDateOfBirth =
    (SELECT TOP(1) athlete.athleteDateOfBirth
     FROM athlete
     ORDER BY athlete.athleteDateOfBirth ASC)
GROUP BY teamName,
         athleteFirstName,
         athleteLastName;
```

Comment: Hi Khoa! Thanks for the reply :) I got an error here -> https://i.imgur.com/TYAds2r.png

Comment: SELECT athleteFirstName, athleteLastName, teamName FROM team t JOIN athlete a ON t.teamId = a.teamId WHERE athleteDateOfBirth = (SELECT TOP(1) athlete.athleteDateOfBirth FROM athlete ORDER BY athlete.athleteDateOfBirth ASC) GROUP BY teamName, athleteFirstName, athleteLastName;

Comment: Wrong Table , Try it Again

Answer (score 0):

Changing the table in subquery to `athlete`.

```
SELECT athleteFirstName, athleteLastName, teamName
FROM team t JOIN athlete a ON t.teamId = a.teamId
WHERE athleteDateOfBirth = (SELECT MAX(athleteDateOfBirth) FROM athlete)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve it using `Limit` or `TOP` key word. For SQL Server use `top` and for MYSql/PostgreSQL Use `Limit`.

**SQL SERVER:**

```
Select top 1 t.TName AS TeamName,a.AName AthleteName,a.athleteDateOfBirth from teamT as t
INNER JOIN athleteT AS a ON t.TeamID=a.TeamID
ORDER BY athleteDateOfBirth DESC;
```

**Link**: [Demo Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/32fed/1/0).

**MySQL / PostgreSQL:**

```
Select t.TName AS TeamName,a.AName AthleteName,a.athleteDateOfBirth from teamT as t
INNER JOIN athleteT AS a ON t.TeamID=a.TeamID
ORDER BY athleteDateOfBirth DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

**LINK**: [Demo Code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32fedc/4/0).

Comment: THanks! this also worked! I was using SQL Server. I just had to change ASC to DESC and add the group by my teacher wanted :D Thanks guys

Comment: Yes I have also updated the answer @RachelD.